# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Transaction'

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and writing the following query

```
INSERT INTO Transaction (TransactionType, AccountID, HolderName, Amount, CurrDate) 
VALUES ('Cash Withdrawal', '25', 'abc', '1000', 'abc');
```

and the script for table is

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
      ,[TransactionType]
      ,[AccountID]
      ,[HolderName]
      ,[Amount]
      ,[CurrDate]
  FROM [ATMSoftware].[dbo].[Transaction]
```

and `ID` is the primary key and auto incremented. But I am getting the error on the insert query

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Transaction'.

Please help me

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [Transaction](TransactionType, AccountID, HolderName, Amount, CurrDate) 
VALUES ('Cash Withdrawal', '25', 'abc', '1000', 'abc');
```

This will surely work for you...Because Transaction is a `KeyWord` in sql management.
i also had similar problem once and `[]` helped me to come out of it.

Vote up or accept if it works for you..

Answer (score 10):

[`Transaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) is a reserved keyword in SQL Server. You need to enclose the table name in `[]` to tell SQL Server it is a name and not a keyword:

```
INSERT INTO [Transaction] 
       (TransactionType,AccountID,HolderName,Amount,CurrDate) 
VALUES 
       ('Cash Withdrawal','25','abc','1000','abc');
```

Answer (score 8):

`Transaction` is a [reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). Put it in brackets.

```
INSERT INTO [Transaction](TransactionType, AccountID, HolderName, Amount, CurrDate) 
    VALUES ('Cash Withdrawal', '25', 'abc', '1000', 'abc');
```

When in doubt, put object names in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

you need to enclosed your tablename which is Transaction with **[** and **]**. Transaction is a reserved word.